# Updated query is not properly working

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Blocked period and the whole column of blocked period value i can't update it**

I had a faculty and admin page.if admin blocks some period it should block.And after that faculty can pick there subject.I have done almost everything. If the faculty select the last hour is selected i could not update the whole row and column value is not working database.my query how its works is if the subject value is null and hour1 value is true then only update query should work. I will show some of the code which i tired please check and give me some hint to overcome

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="Gv1_RowDataBound" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid1">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="datedif" HeaderText="Day/Hour" SortExpression="datedif" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour1">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn1" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour1" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour1").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour1").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour2">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkColumn2" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour2" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour2").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour2").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox6_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour3">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn3" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour3" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour3").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour3").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour4">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn4" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour4" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour4").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour4").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox4_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour5">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn5" runat="server" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour5" runat="server" Checked='<%# bool.Parse( Eval("hour5").ToString()) %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("hour5").ToString().Equals("False") %>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox5_CheckedChanged" OnClick="Check_Click(this)" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
        </asp:GridView>


 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con1.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into subjectdetails (dd,batch,wk) (select datedif,batch,daywk from datelist where batch = '" + ddlbatch.SelectedValue + "' and WeekMonth ='" + ddlmonths.SelectedValue + "')", con1);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con1.Close();
            }
            using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {

                foreach (GridViewRow r in Gv1.Rows)
                {
                    if (
                        (
                        (
                        (
                           (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour1"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour1"))).Checked == false)
                        || (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour2"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour2"))).Checked == false)
                        || (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour3"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour3"))).Checked == false)
                        || (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour4"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour4"))).Checked == false)
                        || (((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour5"))).Checked == true || ((CheckBox)(Gv1.Rows[r.RowIndex].FindControl("chkHour5"))).Checked == false)
                        )
                        )
                        )
                        )
                    {
                        bool hours1 = (r.FindControl("chkHour1") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        bool hours2 = (r.FindControl("chkHour2") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        bool hours3 = (r.FindControl("chkHour3") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        bool hours4 = (r.FindControl("chkHour4") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        bool hours5 = (r.FindControl("chkHour5") as CheckBox).Checked;
                        object subject1 = DBNull.Value, subject2 = DBNull.Value, subject3 = DBNull.Value, subject4 = DBNull.Value, subject5 = DBNull.Value;
                        bool hour1 = true;
                        bool hour2 = true;
                        bool hour3 = true;
                        bool hour4 = true;
                        bool hour5 = true;
                        string datedif = r.Cells[0].Text;


                        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select subject1,hour1 from test", con2);
                        con2.Open();
                        SqlDataReader rdr1 = com1.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr1.Read())
                        {
                            subject1 = rdr1["subject1"];
                            hour1 = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr1["hour1"]);
                        }
                        con2.Close();


                        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("select subject2,hour2 from test", con2);
                        con2.Open();
                        SqlDataReader rdr2 = com2.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr2.Read())
                        {
                            subject2 = rdr2["subject2"];
                            hour2 = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr2["hour2"]);
                        }
                        con2.Close();


                        SqlCommand com3 = new SqlCommand("select subject3,hour3 from test", con2);
                        con2.Open();
                        SqlDataReader rdr3 = com3.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr3.Read())
                        {
                            subject3 = rdr3["subject3"];
                            hour3 = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr3["hour3"]);
                        }
                        con2.Close();


                        SqlCommand com4 = new SqlCommand("select subject4,hour4 from test", con2);
                        con2.Open();
                        SqlDataReader rdr4 = com4.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr4.Read())
                        {
                            subject4 = rdr4["subject4"];
                            hour4 = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr4["hour4"]);
                        }
                        con2.Close();


                        SqlCommand com5 = new SqlCommand("select subject5,hour5 from test", con2);
                        con2.Open();
                        SqlDataReader rdr5 = com5.ExecuteReader();
                        while (rdr5.Read())
                        {
                            subject5 = rdr5["subject5"];
                            hour5 = Convert.ToBoolean(rdr5["hour5"]);
                        }
                        con2.Close();
                        SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand();
                        SqlCommand comm2 = new SqlCommand();
                        SqlCommand comm3 = new SqlCommand();
                        SqlCommand comm4 = new SqlCommand();
                        SqlCommand comm5 = new SqlCommand();
                        con2.Open();

                        if (subject1 == DBNull.Value && hour1)
                        {
                            comm1.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject1=@subject1,hours1 =@hour1 where datedif=@datedif";
                            comm1.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            comm1.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject1=subject1,hours1=hour1";
                            comm1.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        if (subject2 == DBNull.Value && hour2)
                        {
                            comm2.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject2=@subject2,hours2 =@hour2 where datedif=@datedif";
                            comm2.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            comm2.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject2=subject2,hours2=hour2";
                            comm2.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        if (subject3 == DBNull.Value && hour3)
                        {
                            comm3.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject3=@subject3,hours3=@hour3 where datedif=@datedif";
                            comm3.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            comm3.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject3=subject3,hours3=hour3";
                            comm3.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        if (subject4 == DBNull.Value && hour4)
                        {
                            comm4.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject4=@subject4,hours4 =@hour4 where datedif=@datedif";
                            comm4.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            comm4.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject4=subject4,hours4=hour4";
                            comm4.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        if (subject5 == DBNull.Value && hour5)
                        {
                            comm5.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject5=@subject5,hours5=@hour5 where datedif=@datedif";
                            comm5.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            comm5.CommandText = "UPDATE test SET subject5=subject5,hours5=hour5";
                            comm5.Connection = con2;
                        }
                        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject1", ddlsubj.SelectedValue);
                        comm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject2", ddlsubj.SelectedValue);
                        comm3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject3", ddlsubj.SelectedValue);
                        comm4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject4", ddlsubj.SelectedValue);
                        comm5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subject5", ddlsubj.SelectedValue);
                        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedif", datedif);
                        comm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedif", datedif);
                        comm3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedif", datedif);
                        comm4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedif", datedif);
                        comm5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datedif", datedif);
                        comm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour1", hours1);
                        comm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour2", hours2);
                        comm3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour3", hours3);
                        comm4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour4", hours4);
                        comm5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hour5", hours5);
                        comm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        comm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        comm3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        comm4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        comm5.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con2.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Sir, if you can point out the exact location of the error, that would be helpful for us.

Comment: Am not getting the error.Its getting updating but not properly.Admin blocked the particular period.The whole column i can't be updated all other is getting updated